# Spotify Web API slow from Azure in Europe - resolving to wrong country

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, dns, spotify

Using Azure, DNS resolution to:  https://api.spotify.com/  resolves to 194.68.30.55 which is in the US.  From Europe this gives 200ms pings

Amazon EC2 from Ireland works fine resolving to 194.132.197.198 in 11ms

How to force Azure to use European Spotify servers?

Ideally I'm looking for https://uk.api.spotify.com  or something like that..

I could change the hosts file on the VM to force it to an IP at a last resort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you contact Azure regarding this. Also, these IPs may change at any time, so I'd recommend not hardcoding them.

Update: According to the comment by Dave Mateer, this issue has been resolved.

Comment: Many thanks michaelt - have got a question on their Forums.. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09c8c11b-25d5-415a-9c24-7ed16e2d9d07/spotify-web-api-slow-from-azure-in-europe-dns-resolving-to-wrong-country?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork will report back

Comment: Got a response and found the issue is not limited to api.spotify.com - can replicate with www.cnn.com and fastcompany.com....interesting.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now